# xdotool getwindowfocus windowclose

Tags: xdotool

What's the difference between `xdotool getwindowfocus windowclose` and the command executed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>?

Firefox complains when being closed by the former method but doesn't complain when using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, so there must be a difference but I can't seem to understand it.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85205/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-a-close-event-on-various-windows-using-the-terminal

Comment: The answers there are a bit too complex and seem address something different unfortunately.

Comment: The answers explain if you want you can simply send ALT+F4 to the program using xdotool instead.

Comment: hmm, "xdotool key alt+f4 --window getwindowfocus" would be the command yes? But it doesn't work with a keyboard shortcut for some reason. I've now seen that "xdotool getwindowfocus windowkill" works as alt+f4 though, so I'll probably stick to that.

Comment: Not true, the correct command is apparently "wmctrl -c :ACTIVE:"